# I produce 365 items in one hour and 4000 in 10.95 hour how to set when it will complet by time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Let's say i logged in today 9:00 AM and end up 5:00 PM i have to produce 4000 items i know it will exceed the time because my software will stop working at 5 PM so tomorrow when i start working again what would be date and time of completion work

```
What i did
bring working hour =SUM(B2-A2)
total complete work=ROUND(D2/C2, 2)
```

Comment: Will you please add more detail about what you need? What you wrote does not make much sense, the way it is written.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you can use the simple difference of times and correct formatting for the time cells to get the remaining hours

[image]

The Formula in cell C5 is simple =C1-C3

The formatting applied to the cells is as below

[image]

10.95 hours is equal to 10 hours and 57 (95% of 60) minutes
You can write 10:57:00 instead of 10.95

To convert the time to again a number you can divide the time by 0.041666667 and set the format to general